# Kendo Scheduler TimeLineView for Resources, show each event as if its allDay event

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I created this [Dojo Link](https://dojo.telerik.com/ujUZaPAF/3) that shows me resource by group. problem with this view is it shows long block only if it's a allDay event. for this view how can i apply a template that show a block with time range for each event?

currently it is showing small block and its hard to tell what it is or how long it is booked for.

[image: Before]

I want all the event block to take full length despite the duration length.
similar to one highlighted below
[image: After]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot so that we'll see what you've described?

Comment: @Shai added screenshot of before and after( what i wanted)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code snippet below. I did a couple of things:

1. I removed the `title` data from the template of the event since you said you didn't want to see it.
2. I placed a `space` in the template after the `<p>` element so that the `x` action of the event will have a place to appear in. There are other ways to do this, I used a simple one.
3. I've made changes to the styles at the bottom of the code, specifically the following:

   ```
   .movie-template {
       overflow: auto !important;
       width: fit-content !important;
   }

   .k-event {
       width: fit-content !important;
   }

   .space {
       width: 20px;
       height: 15px;
       display: inline-block;
   }

   .movie-template p {
       margin: 5px 0 0;
       display: inline-block;
   }
   ```

**EDIT**
~~~~
Making the appointments fill the cells they belong to is either impossible or extremely complicated. I'll explain why:

The way the events are programmed, they exist on the same level on the DOM as the table of the scheduler and float above it. The scheduler calculates the position and size of the events based on their start and end times.

In order for you to place them as if they are full-day events you need to do one of two things:

1. Override the scheduler's automatic placement, with your own code that will calculate the position and size and set them accordingly. Note that this code will need to run every time the window is resized, re-focused, rotated and so on.
2. Define the events as "whole-day appointments" and store their real start and end times in other fields that you will use in your code. This might break other functionality you might already have in place.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/resources-grouping-vertical">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.timezones.min.js"></script>
    

</head>
<body>
<div id="example" class="k-content">
    <div id="scheduler"></div>
</div>
  <script id="event-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div class="movie-template" style="width:100px">
        <p>#: kendo.toString(start, "hh:mm") # - #: kendo.toString(end, "hh:mm") #</p>
        <span class="space"></span>
    </div>
</script>
<script>
            var MyCustomTimelistView = kendo.ui.TimelineMonthView.extend({
          options: {
            name: "MyCustomTimelistView",
            title: "Timeline Week",
            selectedDateFormat: "{0:D} - {1:D}",
            selectedShortDateFormat: "{0:d} - {1:d}",
            majorTick: 1440,
            numberOfDays: 7
          },
          name: "MyCustomTimelistView",
          calculateDateRange: function() {
            //create the required number of days

            var start = this.options.date,
                //  start = kendo.date.dayOfWeek(selectedDate, this.calendarInfo().firstDay, -1),
                idx, length,
                dates = [];

            for (idx = 0, length = this.options.numberOfDays; idx < length; idx++) {
              dates.push(start);
              start = kendo.date.nextDay(start);
            }
            this._render(dates);
          },
          previousDate: function() {
            var date = new Date(this.startDate());

            date.setDate(date.getDate() - this.options.numberOfDays);

            return date
          }
        });
  
$(function() {
  
  

  
  
    $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
        date: new Date("2013/6/13"),
        startTime: new Date("2013/6/13 07:00 AM"),
        height: 600,
              eventTemplate: $("#event-template").html(),

        views: [
            "day",
            { type: "MyCustomTimelistView", selected: true,
            

            },
            "month",
            "agenda",
            "timeline"
        ],
        timezone: "Etc/UTC",
         dataBinding: function(e) {
            var view = this.view();
           $( ".k-scheduler-times > table > tbody > tr:eq(1)" ).hide();
            $( ".k-scheduler-header-wrap > table > tbody > tr:eq(1)" ).hide();
        },
      
        dataSource: {
            batch: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                update: {
                    url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/update",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                create: {
                    url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/create",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/destroy",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "meetingID",
                    fields: {
                        meetingID: { from: "MeetingID", type: "number" },
                        title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                        start: { type: "date", from: "Start" },
                        end: { type: "date", from: "End" },
                        startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
                        endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
                        description: { from: "Description" },
                        recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                        recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                        recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                        roomId: { from: "RoomID", nullable: true },
                        attendees: { from: "Attendees", nullable: true },
                        isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        group: {
            resources: ["Rooms"],
            orientation: "vertical"
        },
        resources: [
            {
                field: "roomId",
                name: "Rooms",
                dataSource: [
                    { text: "Meeting Room 101", value: 1, color: "#6eb3fa" },
                    { text: "Meeting Room 201", value: 2, color: "#f58a8a" }
                ],
                title: "Room"
            },
            {
                field: "attendees",
                name: "Attendees",
                dataSource: [
                    { text: "Alex", value: 1, color: "#f8a398" },
                    { text: "Bob", value: 2, color: "#51a0ed" },
                    { text: "Charlie", value: 3, color: "#56ca85" }
                ],
                multiple: true,
                title: "Attendees"
            }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
<style>
    .movie-template {
      overflow: auto !important;
      width: fit-content !important;
    }
  
    .k-event {
      width: fit-content !important;
    }
  
    .space {
        width: 20px;
        height: 15px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
  
    .movie-template img {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 8px;
    }
    .movie-template p {
        margin: 5px 0 0;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .movie-template h3 {
        padding: 0 0 5px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .movie-template a {
        color: #ffffff;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .k-state-hover .movie-template a,
    .movie-template a:hover {
        color: #000000;
    }
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i want each event block to take whole day , appear as if it is for full day, even if its just for couple hours on that day. above it seems it goes to another day and does not align with other events on same day

Comment: Edited my answer, see "EDIT".

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom views like this and use it in your code

```
  var CustomMonthView = kendo.ui.TimelineMonthView.extend({
  options: {
    name: "CustomMonth",
    title: "Month"
  },
  name: "CustomMonth",
  _positionEvent: function(eventObject) {
    var eventHeight = this.options.eventHeight + 2;
    var rect = eventObject.slotRange.innerRect(eventObject.start, eventObject.end, true);
    var left = this._adjustLeftPosition(rect.left);
    var width = rect.right - rect.left - 2;
    if (width < 0) {
      width = 0;
    }
    if (width < this.options.eventMinWidth) {
      var slotsCollection = eventObject.slotRange.collection;
      var lastSlot = slotsCollection._slots[slotsCollection._slots.length - 1];
      var offsetRight = lastSlot.offsetLeft + lastSlot.offsetWidth;
      width = this.options.eventMinWidth;
      if (offsetRight < left + width) {
        width = offsetRight - rect.left - 2;
      }
    }
    eventObject.element.css({
      top: eventObject.slotRange.start.offsetTop + eventObject.rowIndex * (eventHeight + 2) + 'px',
      left: left,
      width: width
    });
  },
  _arrangeRows: function (eventObject, slotRange, eventGroup) {
    var startIndex = slotRange.start.index;
    var endIndex = slotRange.end.index;
    var rect = eventObject.slotRange.innerRect(eventObject.start, eventObject.end, true);
    var rectRight = rect.right + this.options.eventMinWidth;
    var events = kendo.ui.SchedulerView.collidingEvents(eventObject.slotRange.events(), startIndex, endIndex);
    slotRange.addEvent({
      slotIndex: startIndex,
      start: startIndex,
      end: endIndex,
      rectLeft: rect.left,
      rectRight: rectRight,
      element: eventObject.element,
      uid: eventObject.uid
    });
    events.push({
      start: startIndex,
      end: endIndex,
      uid: eventObject.uid
    });
    var rows = kendo.ui.SchedulerView.createRows(events);
    if (eventGroup.maxRowCount < rows.length) {
      eventGroup.maxRowCount = rows.length;
    }
    for (var idx = 0, length = rows.length; idx < length; idx++) {
      var rowEvents = rows[idx].events;
      for (var j = 0, eventLength = rowEvents.length; j < eventLength; j++) {
        eventGroup.events[rowEvents[j].uid].rowIndex = idx;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

hope this helps